# Query on PID's in Strace command

Tags: linux, strace

I execute the following strace command with the intention of getting data about PID 13221

```
strace -fF -tT -all -o abc.txt -p 13221
```

However when the command executes and finishes I get output like below :

```
Process 13221 attached with 12 threads - interrupt to quit
Process 13252 attached
Process 13253 attached (waiting for parent)
Process 13253 resumed (parent 13252 ready)
Process 13252 suspended
Process 13252 resumed
Process 13253 detached
Process 13252 detached
Process 13232 detached
Process 13228 detached
Process 13225 detached
Process 13222 detached
Process 13221 detached
```

What are these extra PID's ? Are these the children of 13221 ? Who is creating them ?

Thanks.

Comment: It must have been threads of your program. You have used "-f". Please add to your question this info: cat /proc/13221/tasks

Comment: I tried for a different Process and I did a strace for it and yes in /proc/PID/task/  some of these ID's are present. Are these thread id's or process ids ?? I think its dumb, they should be processes as they are in /proc/

Comment: As for `Are these thread id's or process ids `. On Linux threads are processes. They also have PIDs

Comment: @skwllsp : How to know which of these are threads

Comment: On Linux everything threads are processes. POSIX Threads in a process are started by a main thread and has PPID (parent PID) equal to PID of a main thread

Comment: @skwllsp : I found one more way. Take a pstack of the process all the thread id's are listed there. Anything out of this number is a spawned process.

Comment: `How to know which of these are threads`: If you run `ls /proc/<PID>/task` for your process you will get PIDs of all threads in your process. It is simpler to do when you need to get thread PIDs. `pstack` is a gdb script, it stops a process when attaches. So it is simpler just to run `ls /proc/<PID>/task`

Comment: @skwllsp : Thanks dude. Why dont you post this as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks for the knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are these extra PID's ? Are these the children of 13221 ?

It must have been threads of your program. You have used "-f" in strace and this is why threads are also monitored.

> How to know which of these are threads

If you run `ls /proc/<PID>/task` for your process you will get PIDs of all threads in your process (including a PID of the main thread).

It is simpler to do when you need to get thread PIDs comparing with running `pstack` for the same process. `pstack` is actually a `gdb` script, it stops a process when attaches. So it is simpler just to run `ls /proc/<PID>/task`